# Unable to assign Active class to buttons after dynamically creating them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a tab of buttons using bootstrap .I made them dynamically by using a loop.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom:0px">
   <li class="active">
      <a data-toggle="tab" class="mybtn" id=' + mapport.selected_feature_layer[i] + '>' + layer_names[i] + '</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And When I assign them an active class it worked for me .But after I assign them a class and call a function `self.click($(this).attr('id'));`  the class **active** disappears and the design disappears of the class **active**.

Why this is happening ?

```
 $(".mybtn").click(function(){
    self.click($(this).attr('id'));
    $('.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

Comment: what is `self.click($(this).attr('id'));` include also in OP

Comment: @guradio Click is a function to which I am passing Id of currently pressed button. Self is used as I am using this function globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the click function in a different way in order to make it work for dynamically added elements

```js
$(document).on("click", ".mybtn", function(){
    //self.click($(this).attr('id'));
    $('.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

```css
.active {background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom:0px"><li><a data-toggle="tab" class="mybtn" id='abc'>abc</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" class="mybtn" id='abc'>abc</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: I edited the snippet to include a color for the active element and added another <li> element. You had <li> as active, in my code the <a> is active because that is what you click on. Furthermore, the self.click is deactivated.

Comment: till here I have done already .I mentioned in question that "When I use  "self.click($(this).attr('id'));"  then problem occur. Without using this its working fine. I need solution If I can use both (function call and active class) in a same function or anyother soloution

Comment: thank you I was call from 2 functions that's why overwriting was happening.